# How to assign variable to json property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have data from server that i want to add it to json property but its not displaying , I understand json except only primitive types but how can i add data dynamically to json property ? Foe example in below code i am trying to assign diagramName to "text".

ctrl.js

```
 var diagramName = "";
$scope.data = resp.data;
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(diagram) {
    diagramName = JSON.stringify(diagram.name);
    console.log(diagram.name);
});

     [{
               "id": 1,
               "text": "My Folder",
               "children": [{
                   "id": 10,
                   "owner": "John Smith",
                   "text": diagramName,
                   "string": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>}]
               }]
```

Comment: Simple: You don't. JSON is a transport format. You don't mess with it directly. You decode it to a native data structure, modify that, then re-encode.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` creates a JSON string. If you want to add data to it, modify the object before stringifying it.

Comment: modify the object before stringify ? i did not get it can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

add the dynamic value to the property, before stringifying it:

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(diagram) {
  diagram.text = diagramName
  diagramName = JSON.stringify(diagram.name);
});
```

Comment: within the context of your function, diagram is the item being iterated upon. access it as the first item in the array. diagram[0]